# How to list all objects of Custom Resource Definition (CRD), e.g. when CRDs conflict?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

> **Background**: A while ago cert-manager introduced a breaking change in their CRDs. This leads to two CRDs having the name `order`, which can be seen in `kubectl api-resources`

**How can I list orders from just the newer CRD?**

I recall there was something like `kubectl get acme.cert-manager.io/order` (which is not correct), but cannot piece together anymore.

An excerpt of `kubectl api-resources | grep "order"` would be

```
orders                                         acme.cert-manager.io           true         Order
orders                                         certmanager.k8s.io             true         Order
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to get specific resource using below commands

To get list of `orders` in `acme.cert-manager.io`

```
kubectl get orders.acme.cert-manager.io
```

To get list of `orders` in `certmanager.k8s.io`

```
kubectl get orders.certmanager.k8s.io
```

Comment: Now `kubectl get --help` makes more sense also `Usage:
  kubectl get
[(-o|--output=)json|yaml|wide|custom-columns=...|custom-columns-file=...|go-template=...|go-template-file=...|jsonpath=...|jsonpath-file=...]
(TYPE[.VERSION][.GROUP] [NAME | -l label] | TYPE[.VERSION][.GROUP]/NAME ...) [flags] [options]`

Comment: Also for ref this documentation attempt https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/63299/files